# Ggplot: geom_bar producing "fat" columns

Tags: r, pipe, bar-chart

I have:

```
> myData
      esito cella
43575     R     1
42446     R     1
49653     R     1
65053     R     4
72893     R     4
58299     R     4
61609     R     4
65377     R     4
70783     R     4
71949     R     4
65939     R     4
60434     R     4
```

Then I want to plot them such that I obtain (1,2,3,4) on the x-axis and the number of the elements on the y-axis. For example, since I have 3 elements in the position 1 I want the bar related to x=1 of height 3, etc. Summarizing,
I would expect:

1. x = 1 --> bar with height 3
2. x = 2 --> no bar
3. x = 3 --> no bar
4. x = 4 --> bar with height 9

So I write:

```
myData %>% 
  group_by(cella) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(n =n()) %>%
  unique() %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x= cella, y=n), col="blue") + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity', fill='purple', colour="white") + #, position='dodge'
  ggtitle("Riggio rules")+
  xlab("X")+
  ylab("number")
```

It results:

[image]

So I obtain two bars, but too large.
If I add `+ xlim(c(0, 4))` to the ggplot it plots... nothing!

EDIT:

```
> dput(myData)
structure(list(esito = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("B", "P", "R"), class = "factor"), 
    cella = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L)), .Names = c("esito", 
"cella"), row.names = c(43575L, 42446L, 49653L, 65053L, 72893L, 
58299L, 61609L, 65377L, 70783L, 71949L, 65939L, 60434L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: is x numerical or a factor?

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(myData)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `width` parameter to control the fatness. Here is how it looks like when `width = 1`:

```
myData %>% 
     group_by(cella) %>%
     dplyr::mutate(n =n()) %>%
     unique() %>% 
     ggplot(., aes(x= cella, y=n), col="blue") + 
     geom_bar(stat='identity', fill='purple', colour="white", width = 1) + #, position='dodge'
     ggtitle("Riggio rules")+
     xlab("X")+
     ylab("number")
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, you beat me to it by 50 seconds...nice suggestion!

Comment: It works perfectly! I don't know why sometimes R tries to understand our intentions instead of doing the simplest thing. Anyway, thanks again!